# Yii2 One field in different tabs of buttflattery\yii2-formwizard

Tags: forms, yii2, yii2-formwizard

Now I am workin on complex quiz App on Yii2. Here is MCQ test that contains more than 100 questions. I want to separate this questions into 5 form tabs (so that questions from 1 to 20 in tab1, from 21 to 40 in tab2 etc). Could someone explain what is the way to do this? So, there is only one model and one form submit.

I thought about using the [buttflattery\yii2-formwizard](https://github.com/buttflattery/yii2-formwizard). In the documentation, I have found the Single Model Across Steps tutorial, but it is not really suitable for my case because all questions are written in one field as many rows.

For now `Answers` Model is following:

```
class Answers extends ActiveRecord
{
  public function rules(){
    return[
      [['id','question_id', 'option_id',  'user_id'], 'required'],
    ];
  }
}
```

index view:

```
//start form
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
   'id' => 'my-form-id',
   'action' => ['answers/save'],
   'options' =>['class'=>['t-form']]
   ]); 
?> 
//foreach question:
  <?php for ($i=0; $i<count($questions); $i++): ?> 
    <div class="input-title">
      <?= Html::encode("{$questions[$i]->title}") ?>
    </div>

    <?php $options = Options::find()-> where 
      (['question_id'=>$questions[$i]->id]) ->all();
      $options = ArrayHelper::map($options,'id', 'title');?>
    //print options:
    <div class="radio__wrapper">  
      <?= $form->field($model, 'option_id')->radioList(
        $options, 
        ['name'=>'Questions['.$questions[$i]->id.']', 
         'separator' => '<br>',
         'required'=>true],)->label(false) ?>     
    </div>
   //submit form
    <?= Html::submitButton('Save', ['class' => 'submit']) ?>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); }
```

AnswersController:

```
public function actionSave(){        
  $request = \Yii::$app->request;
  foreach($request->post('Questions') as $key=>$value) {
    $model = new Answers();
    $model->load($request->post());
    $model->option_id = $value;
    $model->question_id = $key;
    $model->user_id = \Yii::$app->user->id;
    $model->save(false);
  }
  if( $model->save(false)){
    return $this->redirect(['result/index']);
  }
}
```

If FormWizard is not suitable variant please explain me what is the most efficient way?

Comment: it not only support  [single model for all steps](https://yii2plugins.omaraslam.com/formwizard/single-model), but it can use separate models for every step or [multiple models for a single step](https://yii2plugins.omaraslam.com/formwizard/multiple-model) too

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam Yes, you are right. But I cannot use separate models because all answers should be posted at once

Comment: i dont get what you are saying if you are concerned about posting all the answers in one go, then there shouldnt be any problem because the wizard do exactly that it will submit all the answers after the last step when you press finish button not before that. So what are you trying to ask here ?

Comment: do mark the answer if it helped you out

Answer (score 0):

[yii2-formwizard](https://github.com/buttflattery/yii2-formwizard) does provide you with a lot of options, which create a form wizard using the `ActiveForm` and `Models`.

### Prominent Features

- You can use a single model across all steps.
- Separate model dedicated to every step.
- Multiple models to a single step.
- Disable/Enable validation.
- Customize & order form fields.
- Tabular Steps with <kbd>Add Row</kbd> button to add fields dynamically like Adress book.
- Form Persistence (saves the un-saved form to be restored later using `localstorage`).
- Preview Step ( Previews all the form input with labels as the last step, and navigates to the step when clicked).
- Multiple Themes

### Demos

You can see the [DEMOS](http://yii2plugins.omaraslam.com/formwizard/index) with all available variations and for Documentation use the [Wiki](https://github.com/buttflattery/yii2-formwizard/wiki)

### SETUP

use composer to install the extension

`php composer.phar require  buttflattery/yii2-formwizard "@dev"`

or add into the composer.json file under require section

`"buttflattery/yii2-formwizard":"@dev"`

### Sample Code

```
use buttflattery\formwizard\FormWizard;

$shootsModel = new Shoots();
$shootTagModel = new ShootTag();

echo FormWizard::widget([
    'steps'=>[
        [
            'model'=>$shootsModel,
            'title'=>'My Shoots',
            'description'=>'Add your shoots',
            'formInfoText'=>'Fill all fields'
        ],
        [
            'model'=> $shootTagModel,
            'title'=>'My Shoots',
            'description'=>'Add your shoots',
            'formInfoText'=>'Fill all fields'
        ],
    ]
]);
```